# Error in the pull function; keepalive request failed for '...' when opening URL, retrying with new connection

Tags: ffmpeg, compiler-errors, discord.py, bots

I'm coding a bot to stream live music for youtube to discord using discord.py and ffmpeg. I used a music cog. However, the bot seems to sometimes have micro lags and even though I want my bot to stay in the voice channel it sometimes leaves. I've hosted my bot on a server but I have regularly this type of error:

```
[tls @ *hex number* ] Error in the pull function.
[hls @ *hex number* ] keepalive request failed for ' *huge link* ' when opening url, retrying with new connection
```

I don't understand where those errors come from.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this error you can add `-http_persistent 0` to your `ffmpeg` options

Comment: my m3u8 looks like this:
`#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:9.599000, no desc
https://website1.com:1122/stream/16938225.ts
#EXTINF:10.800000, no desc
https://anotherwebsite2.com:3344/stream/16938225.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:9.600000, no desc
https://website1.com:1122/stream/16938225.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST`
I have already add the `-http_persistent 0` parameter, but I still get the error:`Error in the pull function.` Could you help me?